# P-N Diodes in series. Is my solution correct?

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

I have attempted to work out a solution on a short question relating to p-n diodes. Is my solution correct?

The question (from a past paper) :
[image: The question:]
From the question I understand that there are two parts:

1. Give the relationship between the reverse saturation currents of the two diodes.
2. Using the given values, determine the saturation current in diode D2

My attempt:

1.
[image: Attempt at the first part of the question]

Does this seem like an appropriately given relationship between the saturation currents? And is it correct?

2.

[image]

[image]

Im not sure if it's correct to equate the ideal diode equations this way, or if I have calculated VD1 correctly.
Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated, and if anyone has noticed something terribly wrong with my logic, please let me know.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish I could find the diode which gives such a low forward voltage :)

Comment: Peter, the entire question seems confusing to me. It talks about comparing the *reverse* saturation current of both diodes in one place; but then later discusses the saturation current of one with the *reverse* saturation current of the other. Finally, both diodes are supposedly in forward-biased condition (which you assumed in your calcs, as well), and the reverse saturation current doesn't factor in. (Or so I imagine.) So I've no idea where to do with the question beyond where you went with it. But I would be uncomfortable with any answer I cobbled up.

Answer (score 1):

The current should be the same as a single diode, the voltage drop will be double that of a single diode. So if the answer for the current is the same for a single diode, then you are on the right track. The current *has to be the same* for both, because they are in series.

Answer (score 1):

What you are calculating is reverse saturation current of D2 which seems to be plausible as the current is lower than the diode D1.

When connected in series, charge entering should be equal to charge leaving,(Kirchoff's Current Law) which means the current should be same in both. But the voltage distribution depends on the individual properties of the diode.

Your approach seems fine for me